# How to run csv using java and output in browser

Tags: java, jsp, csv

This is my java class for read csv file *testnews.csv*, I want to print this output in web brouser so I use jsp but it shows the error ***void type is not allowed***.

*Testnews.java :*

```
package testnews;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Testnews {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Testnews obj = new Testnews();
  obj.run();
 }

  public void run() {
      /**************************************/
      Date dNow = new Date();
      SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("ddMMyyyy");
      String dt = ft.format(dNow).toString();

    /***************************************/
    String csvFile = ("D://news//"+dt+"//testnews.csv");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
            try {
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
 String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
 System.out.println(country[4] + country[5]);
 }
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
  }
}
```

*index.jsp :*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="testnews.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%
            Testnews tn = new Testnews();
            %>
            <%= tn.run() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

*testnews.csv :*

```
1.0.0.0 1.0.0.255   16777216    16777471    AU  Australia
1.0.1.0 1.0.3.255   16777472    16778239    CN  China
1.0.4.0 1.0.7.255   16778240    16779263    AU  Australia
1.0.8.0 1.0.15.255  16779264    16781311    CN  China
1.0.16.0    1.0.31.255  16781312    16785407    JP  Japan
1.0.32.0    1.0.63.255  16785408    16793599    CN  China
1.0.64.0    1.0.127.255 16793600    16809983    JP  Japan
1.0.128.0   1.0.255.255 16809984    16842751    TH  Thailand
```

Comment: Please reformat your question

Comment: I fixed your formatting... in future, please learn how to post code (indent 4 spaces, eliminate extra blank lines, indent the code consistently).  Also, indicate WHERE the error occurs and copy/paste the actual error message.

Comment: `<%=` expects a value but `run` returns none (since its return type is `void`). Make it return an `String` and put in that `String` the values that you want in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** do that : you are putting the formatting of your page in java code. You should try to find a tutorial on Servlet programming and :

- declare a servlet to handle the URL
- have the servlet read the csv file and put its data in request attributes as a list of lists
- have the servlet forward to a jsp
- create a jsp that will use the request attribute and simply does the formatting

No the direct answer to your problem :

You should have `Testnews.run()` write to a `StringWriter` and return the resulting String.

```
public String run() {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    ...
    pw.println(country[4] + country[5]);
    ...
    return sw.toString();
}
```

but **BEWARE** as you are not formatting in HTML the resulting page will be *bad* ...

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line:

```
<%= tn.run() %>
```

right?

The operator `<%=` it's for reading values. Functions also returs values, as you certainly know. So, if you want the instruction `<%= tn.run() %>` works, you should declare the "run" function and return some value to it.

Instead of calling `System.out.println(country[4] + country[5]);` create one string and concatenate the results. At the end of your function, return it to caller.

Hope it helps.